# Trying to package a specific lib into my jar, ain't working

Tags: java, maven, maven-shade-plugin, maven-eclipse-plugin

I'm unable to package needed libs into my Jar, the shade plugin doesn't give any output of any kind in the console, Making it a littile hard to describe what's happening here, as it's more there lack of.

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>shade</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <artifactSet>
                        <includes>
                            <include>org.javacord:javacord</include>
                        </includes>
                    </artifactSet>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

I take it it shouldn't be done this way?

This is the lib that I'm trying to package:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.javacord</groupId>
    <artifactId>javacord</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.4</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

The console output is pasted here: https://hastebin.com/soxafiqupe.cs

Comment: maven-shade-plugin ignores by default dependencies with scope `provided`.  https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/shade-mojo.html furthermore  I have my doubts that the above dependency is correct cause `<type>pom</type>` means you don't have a jar etc. which can be put on the classpath nor on the module path...I would expect to use `<artifactId>javacord-core</artifactId>`...or the `<artifactId>javacord-api</artifactId>` https://search.maven.org/search?q=org.javacord ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check first if, as [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48211874/maven-shade-plugin-not-executing?rq=1#comment83405816_48212027), your plugin definition is in your pom, not your parent pom (if you have one)

Then make sure (as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42231035/6309)) the `plugin` section is inside a `build` section, not a `build/pluginManagement` one.

If you want more traces, a `mvn -X clean install` would be more verbose.